# Vue not binding data to image src

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having a problem binding data to `src` attribute in image. This is my code where I have `:src` and trying to bind `image` to it. Also I printed `this.image` in `created()` and it is getting printed fine. Here is the code

```
<img class="d-block w-100" :src="image" />

    export default {
      name: 'How',
      data(){
        return{
          image: '../../assets/img/how_to_oka_6.png'
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import that image since it considered as a module like :

```
<img class="d-block w-100" :src="image" />

    export default {
      name: 'How',
      data(){
        return{
          image: require('../../assets/img/how_to_oka_6.png')
        }
      }
    }
```