# Image load failed src: undefined../assets/gov_logo.jpg

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm trying to load images from the assets folder, but it's not working:

[image]

I tried the following things. Please help me.

```html
<img src="@/assets/logo.jpg" />
<img src="../src/assets/logo.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<v-img :src="__static + 'assets/logo.png'"></v-img>
<v-img src="./src/assets/logo.png"></v-img>
<v-img :src="__dirname + '/src/assets/logo.png'"></v-img>
<v-img :src="__static + '../assets/gov_logo.jpg'"></v-img>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bind a :src for an image in the child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950105/how-do-i-bind-a-src-for-an-image-in-the-child-component)

Comment: I'm trying to load image in parent component. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: Yes but what i mean is to use `require` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579284/vue-not-binding-data-to-image-src/55579325#55579325)

Comment: I got Error in data(): "Error: Cannot find module './assets/gov_logo.jpg'". @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: are you providing the right path?

Comment: I got Error in data(): "Error: Cannot find module './assets/logo.png'" . I will post image of path in question. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: I have posted the image. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: I have posted image of errors as well . @BoussadjraBrahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```html
<img src="@/assets/logo.png" />
```

OR

```html
<img :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')" />
```

Your first try would have worked but you used `.jpg` instead of `.png`.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Can I ask one more question. @Dan

Comment: When I use default vue logo inside assets folder ,its working but when I used other images, it doesnot work. I got Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/assets/gov_logo.jpg' @Dan

Comment: It should.  Make sure that you use the right path and filename.  If you want, you can post a comment with a screenshot showing your other image in your project directory, and also show the code you are using to display it.

Comment: What can I do to help?  I assumed you resolved it when you found your path mistake. 
 There is no difference between Vue's logo and any other image, so you'll have to show your code and a screenshot of your project directory.

Comment: image issue was already solved before. Sorry I asked  question in wrong format. Actually i want to ask this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897227/unable-to-display-search-filter-in-individual-column-header-using-vuetify-datata @Dan

Comment: Ah ok good.  I'll take a look at the new question.  If I can help, I'll reply there.